# Rails: How do I group by a column in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, count

My models look like so:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :urgency
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end

class Urgency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

I am trying to display the number of Tasks per Project in a table.  For example, I want to see the table show Project A has 10 tasks and Project B has 7 tasks etc.

Furthermore, I want to then be able to only show the count of tasks in each project where the urgency is high (this would mean taking the urgency_id from the task table and looking up the urgency_name in the Urgency table).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [group](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) method provided by ActiveRecord. Here is an example of the SQL it generates:

> User.group(:name)
>
> => SELECT "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY name

Additionally, you should also have a look at the [count](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count) method provided by ActiveRecord. Here is an example of the SQL it generates:

> Task.count(:project_id)
>
> SELECT COUNT("tasks", "project_id") FROM "tasks"

We can combine these two method together to get the number of tasks per project.

```
Task.group(:project_id).count(:project_id) 
# This returns {1=>2, 2=>3} in my database. This suggests, project1 has 2 tasks, project2 has 3 tasks
```

To achieve your second requirement, we will need to use the rails [joins](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) method.

```
Task.joins(:urgency).where("urgencies.utype = 'High'").group(:project_id).count(:project_id)
# This returns {2=>1}, suggesting project 2 has 1 task where the urgency (utype) is high.
```